# get a json data key value in node.js

Tags: json, node.js

i have  following json data.from this i need to extract os value.
How it can be done using node.js

```
result = data.toString();
```

`console.log(result)`          prints following

```
 [ { _id: '52849a7b8dd61980d1b49b87',          
        id: '70',           
        mode: 'daily',
        os: 'VM-WIN7-64',
        server: '172.16.2.120' } ]
```

i tried `console.log(result.os)`; prints `undefined!`

How can i get `os` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `data` is an array you should be able to do this:

```
console.log(data[0].os);
```

Why are you calling `toString` on `data`? That will return a string, which obviously isn't going to have an `os` property. You need to work with the actual data structure.